# What are imaginary triangles?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-geometry

The condition is that $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ are the sides of a triangle inscribed in a circle of unit diameter determines a (symmetric) compact 2-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose equation may be written:
$$
\sin^{-1} x +\sin^{-1} y + \sin^{-1} z = \pi
\tag{1}
$$
It  intersects each of the planes $x=1,\space y=1$ and $z=1$ in a circle of unit radius.

> **Q**. Can the same equation (1) be used to define a surface in $\mathbb{C}^3$? If so, what can be said about it?

Comment: "Same condition" means what?  The equation in arcsines?  Intersecting three planes in circles?

Comment: @GEdgar my intended meaning was the equation in arcsines. thank you for drawing my attention to this ambiguity. I have adjusted the text accordingly

Comment: @GEdgar btw it would sometimes be useful to be able to add a number reference to an equation for the purpose of cross-reference. would you be so kind as to provide a URL where I can learn how to do this?

Comment: I added number reference, so you can see one way to do it.

Comment: thanks very much. that will certainly meet my needs for now. I suppose there are more sophisticated variants that do auto-renumbering which might be useful in editing longer texts, but for MSE Q & A's just the odd tag is more than adequate.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer but it might interest you.  The condition that three quantities $a$,$b$ and $c$ are the side lengths of a triangle can be written in the algebraic form $$2(b^2 c^2+ c^2 a^2+ a^2 b^2)- a^4 -b^4- c^4>0. $$

If this is the case, then the area of the triangle is, up to a multiplicative factor, equal to the square root of the above expression.  This has induced geometers to
ponder  its significance  when it is negative (triangles with imaginary area, so to speak).  One reference: Kendig, Amer. Math. Monthly, 104(2000), 402.  This, of course, does not address your second condition---on the diameter---but it might nevertheless be relevant.